What is the precise difference between "maximal Cauchy development" and "maximal global hyperbolic development"?
Following the theorem of Choquet-Bruhat and Geroch, we can define the maximal Cauchy development of initial data in the following manner: Theorem 10.2.2 of Wald's 1984 GR book. However, in the literature, I see "maximal global hyperbolic development" used interchangeably (at least, it seems that way to me?).
Can you please indicate the precise difference between "maximal Cauchy development" and "maximal global hyperbolic development"?
(P.S. Please forgive the cross-posting)
